# Orientation issues in Ios 7?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, ios7

Hi I am working on iphone app (not for ipad) which contains orientation in both protrait and landscape. My problem is sometimes orientation is not done. If i turn device to landscape mode, it is stuck in that mode only, not turn to protrait mode and vice versa.

[image]

I dont know the problem. i activated all device orientation modes in deployment info section.

Can anyone tell me the solution for this.

Thanks in advance, 
Mahesh.

Comment: Did you read this?: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1688/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
  UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  statusBarOrientation];
  if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
         // Write your orientation code here.
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        // Write your orientation code here.
    }
}
// For ios5 
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
         // Write orientation code here for ios5
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
         // Write orientation code here for ios5
    }


      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

  }

 // Write code for ios6 and above
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
      return YES;
    }  
    else
       return  NO;
 }
 -(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
 {
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
          // Write orientation code here for ios5
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
         // Write orientation code here for ios5
    }


 }
```